# Conditions for existence and uniqueness of systems with linear and nonlinear equations

Tags: nonlinear-system

Given a system that contains a mixture of linear and nonlinear equations, under what conditions can we guarantee that a solution will exist and that it will be unique?

For example, the system
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2&=c^2 && (1) \\
a+b+c&=1000 && (2)
\end{align}
has a unique solution $$(200, 375, 425)$$ if we additionally restrict $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be integers (some of you may recognize this as problem 9 from Project Euler).

However, if we change $(2)$ to $$a+b+c=k$$ for some arbitrary integer $k$, for what choices of $k$ will we achieve a unique solution?  More generally, when we have ANY system where some equations are linear and others are nonlinear, are there circumstances that allow us guarantee similar outcomes?